Align title to the left in an AccordionItem
I am using an Accordion widget within my sample app (used for learning Kivy).  In my KV code, I have:
    Accordion:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        AccordionItem:
            title: '2024/12/20  00:00    <reference>'
            ...

The title is displayed centered within the AccordionItem header.  I would like to change this to have all the titles aligned to the left.  But I didn't see a way to do this in the documentation for the Accordion widget.
Is there a simple way to do this simple thing???

According to the documentation, you can adjust the title_template which describes how the title is displayed. Try adding this to your kv file:
[AccordionItemTitle@Label]:
    text: ctx.title
    halign: 'left'
    valign: 'center'
    text_size: self.size
    normal_background: ctx.item.background_normal if ctx.item.collapse else ctx.item.background_selected
    disabled_background: ctx.item.background_disabled_normal if ctx.item.collapse else ctx.item.background_disabled_selected
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.disabled_color if self.disabled else self.color
        BorderImage:
            source: self.disabled_background if self.disabled else self.normal_background
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
        PushMatrix
        Translate:
            xy: self.center_x, self.center_y
        Rotate:
            angle: 90 if ctx.item.orientation == 'horizontal' else 0
            axis: 0, 0, 1
        Translate:
            xy: -self.center_x, -self.center_y
    canvas.after:
        PopMatrix

This just adds:
halign: 'left'
valign: 'center'
text_size: self.size

to the template. Which adjusts the title to do what you want. See the Label to understand what is happening.

Hey, thanks, @John Anderson - that worked!  I have to admit I don't really understand this template concept.  Seems like a lot of added code to get this tiny change.  And I was surprised that I didn't need to reference AccordionItemTitle anywhere else in my code...  By the way, PyCharm indicates that halign has a typo! (Strange)
